# Problems with Different versions of IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have designed a web portal, I have made that website good looking at Firefox browser, 
But when I started testing with IE, some issues which works in IE 6 may not work in IE 8,
means back ward compatability is not there in the IE.

You can check my website at [cricket scores](http://www.cricandcric.com)

In this scenario, which IE version do you think to consider and make my website to work normal.

Edit

As per the below suggestions, I understand that need to create the separate CSS file 
corresponding to each IE version like 6, 7,8, 9 and so on in future, 
if the number of CSS files increases, wont that affect the performance and loading of the web page

please advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatley IE does not render things the same as Firefox and is a common problem. The best way is to do IE Specific IF statements and have IE 8 Emulate IE 7. This does require a few additional CSS files, edited for each version. Below is the generic way to have it set up for IE/FF (belongs in head). Normally IE 6 & 7 are viewed the same so you do not need to have different CSS files for them.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/dchirotemplate/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
 <!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style_ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style_ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
```

You can view a site I created with this style sheet setup by going to http://www.decrescenzochiropractic.com

Comment: As per your suggestions, I understand that need to create the separate CSS file 
corresponding to each IE version like 6, 7,8, 9 and so on in future, 
if the number of CSS files increases, wont that affect the performance and loading of the web page
please advice,

Comment: no it will not affect performance because it will only call the css required for the specific IE version. The line <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> forces IE8 and IE9 to render like IE7. Microsoft has a tendecy in IE8 and believe in IE9 as well, they try to further css restrictions so that is why i use that line.

Answer (score 1):

Tip 1: Don't even bother trying to make things look good on IE6. Make it *work* on IE6 if you must, but if you start trying to achieve perfection in IE6 you'll be in for a world of pain and frustration.

We have officially dropped support for IE6 on our new site; we're not even testing with it.

Tip 2: Look into using some javascript libraries that provide better cross-browser compatibility for IE. Here are some good ones:

- [Dean Edwards' IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)
- [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com)
- [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html)
- [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/)
- [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Also consider using jQuery or similar; this is a bigger jump than just compatibility, since it involves changing your coding style quite considerably, but it does provide very good cross-browser compatibility for most of its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [IE-only conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), in the form

```
<!--[if IE 6]> <p>hello world of bugs!</p> <![endif]-->
```

This way you can load custom stylesheets, etc.

You should make your site work with *all browsers*.

A quick and dirty trick for IE 6 and 7 is also the star selector but don't overuse it:

```
body{
    background-color: blue;
    *background-color: red /* Only shown in IE */;
}
```

Fact is IE will be the most troublesome of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, IE has not been compatible, period.

While most of the other browsers were working to be compatible with the standards coming out, MS was trying to be smarter and better than everyone else and doing their own thing. This has caused a lot of problems for many designers. A lot of design books have an entire chapter on dealing with IE's quirks.

Fortunately, it appears MS is finally starting to see the light. To Microsoft's credit, IE8 defaults to a mode that is more standards-compliant that IE7, breaking sites that targeted earlier versions of IE. And, from what I've read, they're as committed as ever to the standards with IE9.

So to answer your question, I'd try and be compatible with the later versions. That way, your site is likely to remain valid for longer. However, any good website designer will test on all the top browsers. I use IE, Chrome, Opera, and FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this all the wrong way.

Yes, you could create separate style sheets, and you may still have to. However, the markup on your page is absolutely atrocious. You are sending every browser that hits that page into quirks mode, and getting pages to look the same, or even function the same, between browsers when they are all in quirks mode is a chore in and of itself. Don't get me wrong, it can be done, but it takes quite a bit of duck tape and bailing wire.

You should really fix your markup, then assess your css. You can definitely make a page that looks like yours with a single style sheet, even in IE6.